# Rename of button as user define is not working after exit from application

Tags: java, android

//Here is my method for rename of button but after exit its not working mean it's not showing rename of user why?

```
void changeNameOne(){
    newNmOne ="";
    lidOne=btn.getText().toString();
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Change Name");
    alert.setMessage("Type in the text you want to set.");
    final EditText ec = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(ec);
    ec.setText(lidOne);
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            newNmOne = ec.getText().toString();
            btn.setText(newNmOne);
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            btn.setText(lidOne);
        }

    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: because you're not saving it

Comment: Try removing `final` from Edittext.

Comment: how can i save it plz put your code according to above code thanks in advance

Comment: @kashyapjimuliya on ec.getText().toString() its showing "variable ec is accessed from inner class try to need final"

Comment: You have to save it somewhere (SharedPreference) and retrieve it from there on resume.

Comment: newNmTwo is the edited text right? in getString u have to use a unique String as the key. something like newNmTwo = sharedPrefs.getString("editTextSaved1","defaultValueIfNotFound"); You have to use "editTextSaved1" also to save it to shared prefs. Then just et.setText(newNmTwo);

Comment: I am using shared preference but still its not working why?
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPref.getString(newNmOne,"");
        super.onResume();
    }

Comment: check my anser mate

Comment: @Memme I have done as like 
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString(newNmTwo,"");
                editor.apply();

                newNmTwo = ed.getText().toString();
                btn.setText(newNmTwo);
            }
        });

Comment: but what i have to do in on resume method?

Comment: Check the anser mate. You are giving newNmTwo as the key in putString, but it is the value not the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following changes:

```
private static final String MYKEY = "myEditText1";
private static final String DEFAULT_TEXT = "I'm a button";

private String newNmOne = DEFAULT_TEXT;

void changeNameOne(){
        lidOne=btn.getText().toString();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Change Name");
        alert.setMessage("Type in the text you want to set.");
        final EditText ec = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(ec);
        ec.setText(lidOne);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                newNmOne = ec.getText().toString();
                btn.setText(newNmOne);
                prefs.putString(MYKEY, newNmOne);////////////here this can be done in onpause too
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                btn.setText(lidOne); //not needed
            }

        });
        alert.show();
    }

    public void onResume(){
         newNmOne = prefs.getString(MYKEY, DEFAULT_TEXT);//if not found set default text
    btn.setText(newNmOne);
    }
```

adjust for ur needs

Comment: I omitted the edit/commit and so on, it's just to show u how to :)

Answer (score -2):

If you need to preserve the text even after app exit, then use SharedPreferences. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html.

Comment: @Downvoter..putting a comment will help to improve my answers.